# Using regex replace // with /

Tags: php, regex

need regular expression for removing `//` to `/` from 'web//wp';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty easy, you just have to properly escape the slashes:

```
preg_replace('/\/\//','/','//');
```

Comment: or use a different delimiter, which I would prefer here to avoid mikado syndrome: `preg_replace('~//~','/','web//wp-content');`

Comment: Ah yes I always forget that, way better than mine!

Comment: thanks Tim Pietzcker & @OschtärEi